# Squashing commits with solved conflicts

Tags: git, github

i want to squash my commits before pushing.
This works fine with "git rebase -i head~#", with # being the number of commits.

Then I want to update my branch to the newest state of the remote repo.
So i do "git pull remoterepo branch" and solve any conflicts.

But here's my problem:
This creates a new commit, which i also want to squash with the commits i made before.
But when i do "git rebase -i head~2" again (to squash this new commit with my last one), the editor spills out a list of ALL the commits seperately that were pulled with the pull-command.

What do i do now, how can i proceed?
Not only i had to edit hundreds of options for each commit here (change "pick" in to "s(quash)"), but also - will my history look clean afterwards? Is this what my collabs would want?

Answer (score 1):

Short version: you probably want to rebase onto their commits.  At this point the easiest way to do that is probably:

```
git fetch origin
git rebase origin/master
```

If you generally want to rebase when combining your code with upstream code, you can configure `git pull` to do that for you, or run `git pull --rebase` (but see the warning in the documentation, and learn what rebase really does; see below).

---

Here's what happened.

1. You made lots of commits, over some period of time.  They were probably all nice and linear, and chained off some older commits you got from the remote:

   ```
   ...-o-o-o                <-- origin/master
            \
             u-u-u-u-u-u    <-- HEAD=master
   ```
2. You chose to "squash" all your commits down to a single `U` commit, whose contents are the same as the last of the little-`u` commits and whose message is whatever you came up with:

   ```
   ...-o-o-o                <-- origin/master
            \
             U              <-- HEAD=master
   ```
3. Alas, in the time it took for you to make the `u` commits and turn them into one big `U` commit, they (whoever they are) generated hundreds of *new* commits.

   Let's draw *their* repo, and the commits they have.  I'll use the `o` for the original ones and `n` for their new ones, but I won't draw in hundreds as that's just too hard:

   ```
   ...-o-o-o-n-n-n-n-n-n   <-- master
   ```

   They don't have your commits, of course—neither the original `u` commits, nor the one big `U` commit you made as a last step of squashing-together the smaller `u` commits.

Now, `git pull` is basically just `git fetch` followed by `git merge`.<sup>1</sup>  In any case, `git fetch` is the first fundamental operation here and the one to look at first.

What `fetch` does is ask your git to call up their git on the Internet-phone<sup>2</sup> and see what's happened "over there" since the last time those two talked to each other.  Your git asks their git what's happened, and they tell you about all the new `n` commits.  Your git has their git send those over, and they get integrated into your repository.  Your git updates your "remote tracking branch", `origin/master`, to be in sync with what their git told them their git-repository looks like now.  So now we can draw what you have in your repo:

```
...-o-o-o-n-n-n-n-n-n   <-- origin/master
         \
          U             <-- HEAD=master
```

You have your one big commit, which you made on top of the last `o` commit.  They have their hundreds of new `n` commits, which they also made on top of the last `o` commit.

You now have a problem.  You must integrate your version, stored under your commit `U`, with their version, adding on to the very last `n`.

Your two options are to *merge*, which makes a new "merge commit" `M`:

```
...-o-o-o-n-n-n-n-n-n     <-- origin/master
         \           \
          U-----------M   <-- HEAD=master
```

or to *rebase*, which takes a series of commits (one `U` commit is just a very short series) and "replays" those commits atop some other commit:

```
...-o-o-o-n-n-n-n-n-n     <-- origin/master
        |            \
        |             U'  <-- HEAD=master
         \
          U               [abandoned]
```

Both the "merge" *and* the "replay" use git's merge machinery, so whichever method you use, the results are pretty similar.  There are two real differences, in the end.

A regular merge uses the merge system in the more obvious way,<sup>3</sup> looking at "what you did" (the diff between the last `o` commit and your `U` commit) and "what they did" (the diff between the last `o` commit and the last `n` commit), and combining these.  If you both made what git thinks is "the same" change, it keeps one copy of that change.  For other changes, git tries to combine them, and if it thinks it succeeded, it charges on; if it needs your help, it stops and makes you resolve the merge conflicts yourself.

(Even if git thinks the merge worked, you should look at the results yourself, because sometimes git thinks it did everything properly but the result is not what you wanted.)

A rebase (replay) uses the merge system more subtly.  To replay your one commit, git compares the work-tree in the commit to the work-tree in the commit before it (i.e., a diff from the-last-`o`-commit to the `U` commit in this case).  However, it also *still* grabs a merge-style diff: the same "last `o` vs last `n`" it gets for a merge.  If you were replaying an entire chain of commits—your series of little `u` commits, for instance—it would compare the first `u` against the last `o`, the second `u` against the first `u`, and so on; and also get the one big merge-style diff.  The rebase then applies each of your commits, but does the same thing merge does: if one of your changes is already there in the last `n` commit, it just keeps the one copy of the change.  (Since you only have one `U` commit to replay, this distinction makes no difference anyway.)

The resulting work-tree is actually the same regardless of whether you merge or rebase.  So what exactly is the difference?  As I said, there are two real differences in the end:

- If you do a merge, you get a merge commit: an extra commit, the one labeled `M` above.  This merge records the fact that your original work—commit `U`, in this case—was done whenever you made that commit.  If you're keeping the whole chain of little `u` commits, this tracks exactly what you did and when you did it: the true history of your work.  Since you made one big `U` commit out of it, this tracks a minor lie, a claim that you made one big commit on top of the last `o` commit.

  The merge also records any changes you had to make in order to take your `U` work-tree—a version of the code that, we might hope, is well tested and works correctly—and combine it with their last `n` commit.  Thus, it lets someone in the future check out the version under `U` and test that, in case there's some problem with the version under `M`.  If the last `n` version works, and your `U` version works, then any bug must have been introduced by combining these two.
- If you do a rebase instead, you will abandon your version `U` and just have a version, `U'`, whose tree is the same as what you'd have in version `M`.  This makes it look like you waited until now, looked at all the `n` commits, and wrote your `U'` version based on those.

  This history is simpler: you woke up a few hours ago, dashed off a huge amount of code, and got it all working, tested it for days, etc., and made commit `U'` (all in the span of a few minutes! amazing! :-) ).  It's not the true history though.  On the other hand, will anyone else really care?  Do they really need merge-commit `M` to retain the semi-true history?  Will that actually aid someone in tracking down a bug in the future?  Or is it just clutter, making the development history harder to read and to follow?

It's not actually possible to know, a priori, which one is better.  Most people mostly seem to prefer the rebased version though—especially if you are already "messing with history" to hide all the little-`u` commits.  I find that the "right answer" varies, myself: little changes, easily rebased, should be rebased.  Big changes with big merge issues ... well, if they can be easily rebased and that makes for fewer merge issues, do that; if not, keep more history, retain more merges, etc.

---

<sup>1</sup>Or, `git fetch` followed by `git rebase`.  If you have a sufficiently new git, there's also a `--rebase=preserve` mode, or you can set `preserve` in the pull configuration, to keep any local merges when rebasing.

<sup>2</sup>Or other communications channel, but "over the net" is the most common update.

<sup>3</sup>Sometimes not all that obvious, actually.

Comment: Wow, great reply!
Big thanks and much respects!

So what do in need to do if i choose the rebase-route and want to squash the new merge commit with my original big U-commit ?

Comment: If you already have a merge commit, but use `git rebase origin/master` (while on branch `master`), git generally deletes the merge commit automatically (that's what the new `--rebase=preserve` is meant for, it uses `git rebase -p` instead of plain `git rebase` in order to *keep* merges).  If you don't have the merge yet, or if you remove it manually, there's nothing for git to get rid of.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `--ff-only` flag on the `git pull` command? Here is a related exert from the [documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull):

```
--ff-only

Refuse to merge and exit with a non-zero status unless the current HEAD is already up-to-date or the merge can be resolved as a fast-forward.
```

I guess the extra commit you have is a merge commit. This is either forced by your configuration, or necessary to resolve some conflict. Git can avoid generating it (fast-forward) under some conditions (e.g. no conflict). The `--ff-only` allows to cancel the execution, unless no extra commit is needed.

Comment: Thx. Is this also possible when there is a conflict?

Comment: When there is a conflict, it is necessary to have a extra commit, which contains the changes to actually merge the two branches. Without this extra commit, Git does not know for sure how to complete the merge. And this extra commit allows to rollback if necessary (by reverting this commit), and have an "exact" history of what is happening to each file and line. Fast forwarding is an optional behaviour: When there is no conflict, it allows just to merge branch without extra commit. You can also choose `--no-ff` to force having the extra commit each time.